did dd make a bad clone?
I have a windows10 nvme drive I cloned using dd if=/dev/nvme bs=4M windows.img
so then, I cloned that image to another nvme drive, and tried to boot windows, but it would not boot. it gives some error like 0x03FF
is there something wrong with this dd command?
I want to clone Windows to a larger nvme, then make the system dual booting.

Normally nvme drives are identified by something like nvme0n1, with nvme0n1p1, nvme0n1p2 etc being their partitions, /dev/nvme would be like saying /dev/sd, which doesn't make too much sense, as you gotta have something to uniquely identify them. Is that the actual command you run? How big is the image you got?

the data is all present, as far as I cant tell.. I can mount the image, I just cant boot it after cloning it to another disk.

I am unsure of how dd handles the arguments but try to specify what the output file is, i.e. use the of option of dd.
dd if=/dev/nvme bs=4M of=windows.img
One other cause of problem when cloning drives is that the system is not synced before the destination device eg, a usb device, is removed. To sync the system just type sync after the dd operation and wait for the prompt to return. Then remove your destination drive.
By the way, you can make the cloning go faster if you use a larger block size, eg 100M.
